# How to acquire and release the locks in OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp

This is my program, which creates certain number of parallel threads and each reader thread cannot read data while any writer thread is writing to it

```
#include<omp.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

omp_lock_t rw_lock;
char data[50];

void readData(int tid){

    while(!omp_test_lock(&rw_lock))
        printf("\n[Thread %d - Reader]: Waiting for data ...",tid);
    printf("\n[Thread %d - Reader]:\t%s",tid,data);
    omp_unset_lock(&rw_lock);

}

void writeData(int tid){

    while(!omp_test_lock(&rw_lock))
        printf("\n[Thread %d - Writer]: Waiting for data ...",tid);
    printf("\n[Thread %d - Writer]\n\tEnter new data:\t",tid);
    scanf(" %[^\n]49s",&data);
    omp_unset_lock(&rw_lock);
}

int main(){

    int read_cnt,write_cnt,wrote=0;

    setbuf(stdout,NULL);

    printf("\nEnter data:\t");
    scanf(" %[^\n]49s",&data);

    printf("\nEnter total Reader and Writer thread count:\t");
    scanf(" %d%d",&read_cnt,&write_cnt);
    omp_init_lock(&rw_lock);

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(read_cnt+write_cnt)
    for(int i=0; i<(read_cnt+write_cnt);i++){
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        if(i<read_cnt){
            readData(tid);
        }else
            writeData(tid);
    }
    omp_destroy_lock(&rw_lock);
    return 0;
}
```

Command used

```
gcc -fopenmp readerwriter.c
```

This program works for only 1 writer thread:

```
Enter data: test word

Enter total Reader and Writer thread count: 4 1

[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 1 - Reader]:    test word
[Thread 3 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]:    test word
[Thread 2 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 2 - Reader]:    test word
[Thread 3 - Reader]:    test word
[Thread 4 - Writer]
    Enter new data: hi
```

But if input two or more writer threads:

```
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...
[Thread 0 - Reader]: Waiting for data ...^C
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which readers / writers are getting the lock is not defined. In your "bad" case, you simply don't see the "Enter new data:" prompt because a reader thread is spamming the console while trying to acquire the lock.

The first step is to get rid of the output in the `test_lock` loop. Then just replace the `test`-loop with a single `omp_set_lock` each.

But that still doesn't guarantee order of reading/writing. If you want to implement a real producer/consumer you should take care of that with a proper queue. Note that OpenMP isn't particularly well suited to implement producer/consumer programs, so you won't get lots of help from it.